# Custom Redactor Setting not Working

Tags: redactor

Craft 2.6.2972

I've created a new redactor config called **Basic Config** and saved the json in craft/config/redactor based on this [Strait Up Craft post](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-to-add-custom-redactor-toolbars-to-the-default-rich-text-field-in-craft-cms). I then created a field and selected the correct config setting and added it to a channel.

However when I go to edit the entry it's not using my config setting as all the formatting options including code etc are there.

[image]

the json is:

```
{
    buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],
    plugins: ['fullscreen'],
    formattingTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']
}
```

Not sure why code, h1, and h2 tags are available when clearly they are not in the above formatting options

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Straight Up Craft article is pretty old and based on the Redactor I API, I believe.

Pretty sure in Redactor II, `formattingTags` got replaced with either [`formatting`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#setting-formatting) or [`formattingAdd`](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/formatting-add/), depending on your needs.